# How to play audio first time when creating customized audio player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to build a custom audio player. Though it seems like a very common doubt, but not sure what is the exact solution for this.

Many browsers don't allow you to call the play() for the first time from javascript(browsers that block autoplay) unless the user has not interacted with the audio play button. But since i am creating a custom player with css, all i am doing is to trigger an event when user clicks on customized play button and then making javascript call the to play() method. What can be the best fix for this ?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pqc8oms/5/)

Seems to run fine in the fiddle, but getting the below error otherwise:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Immediately load the audio in the background. No need to add to DOM
const loadAudio = new Promise(resolve => {
  const audio = new Audio()
  audio.src = 'https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com/audio/opus/demo/96kbit.opus'

  // resolve audio as ready to play when we've fetched enough playback bytes
  audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
    resolve(audio)
  })
})

async function play() {
  // wait for audio to be ready (loadAudio Promise resolved)
  const audio = await loadAudio

  // restart if already playing
  audio.currentTime = 0

  audio.play()
}

async function stop() {
  const audio = await loadAudio
  audio.pause()
}
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: none;
  border: none;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #4c8bf5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="play" type="button" onclick="play()" title="Play">▶</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop()" title="Stop">■</button>
```

Also, consider using Opus and not MP3 for smaller, better quality files.

Comment: Yes this solution seems to work fine. can you please just elaborate a bit for the knowledge perspective about why does adding that particular piece of code worked just fine.